# ModuleNotFoundError in python even after installing the module

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

i run `pip install openpyxl` in cmd, and it installs successfully then i go in IDLE Shell and run `import openpyxl`
i get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

i don't know what's the problem here to recheck it i install another module `pip install requests` now when i call it in IDLE `import requests` i get the same error again
This error might be due to the reason that i have multiple virtual envs installed on my machine which i basically installed after following some udemy courses but i have no idea how those env work, the envs are installed on anaconda.
My Python Version is `3.9.1` and i am on windows 10

Comment: You installed openpyxl in a Conda environment? It might be worth taking a step back and starting fresh, figuring out what virtual environment tools you have installed and how they work.

Comment: I actually don't know what modules are installed in virtual env since it came inbuilt in udemy course and i simply unpacked in zip file they provided

Comment: You should be able to find that out using `conda list`.